# Add Miniconda binaries to path in Docker container

Tags: python, docker, anaconda

I'm using the following commands in my Dockerfile to install Miniconda. After I install it, I want to use the binaries in `~/miniconda3/bin` like `python` and `conda`. I tried exporting the PATH with this new path prepended to it, but the subsequent `pip` command fails (pip is located in `~/miniconda3/bin`.

Curiously, if I run the container in interactive terminal mode, the path is set correctly and I'm able to call the binaries as expected. It seems as though the issue is only when building the container itself.

```
  FROM ubuntu:18.04
  RUN apt-get update
  RUN apt-get install -y python3.7
  RUN apt-get install -y curl 
  RUN curl https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh --output miniconda.sh
  RUN bash miniconda.sh -b
  RUN export PATH="~/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
  RUN pip install pydub # errors out when building
```

Here's the result of `echo $PATH`

```
~/miniconda3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Here's the error I get

```
/bin/sh: 1: pip: not found
```

Answer (score 1):

`export` won't work. Try `ENV`

Replace

```
RUN export PATH="~/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

with

```
ENV PATH="~/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Can you add `RUN echo $(ls ~/miniconda3/bin)` and see if `pip` is installed in ~/miniconda3/bin ?

Comment: Yes, confirmed that it's installed.

Comment: What is the error message you get on `pip` command? `No such file or directory`.

Comment: Yes that’s what I get

Comment: Try echo $PATH and post the results of echo ls and PATH please. Update the question with pip error message also.

Comment: Updated original question.

Comment: Remove `pip` and create the image with build command. Then start the container and exec get bash and then try `pip install xxxx`. Just to debug.

Answer (score 1):

Even though Miniconda is located in `~`, it default installs to the root directory unless otherwise specified.

Here's the right command.

```
RUN export PATH="/root/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `export PATH ...` command is putting the literal symbol `~` into the path. Try this:

```
ENV PATH="$HOME/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
```