# Unable to use miniconda within docker container installing it with Dockerfile

Tags: python, docker, anaconda, miniconda

I want to use miniconda within a container coming from a Dockerfile based on Debian. I have seen several similar questions here

- [Add Miniconda binaries to path in Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56898108/add-miniconda-binaries-to-path-in-docker-container)
- [How to install packages with miniconda in Dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58269375/how-to-install-packages-with-miniconda-in-dockerfile)
- [Problems running conda update in a dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57292146/problems-running-conda-update-in-a-dockerfile)

But I have not been able to make it work with the answers there. My Dockerfile starts with:

```
RUN sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y build-essential gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libcairo2 \
    libcups2 libfontconfig1 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libxss1 fonts-liberation \
    libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget libappindicator3-1 libgbm1 python3-dev nano
```

There is a chunk of code related to miniconda that seems to work during the Dockerfile compilation, which is:

```
ENV PATH="/root/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
ARG PATH="/root/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
RUN wget \
    https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh \
    && mkdir /root/.conda \
    && bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b \
    && rm -f Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
RUN conda --version
```

This doesn't throw any error, but if I enter to a bash console in the generated container, I get `conda command not found` error. Apart from these, I have tried all proposed solutions in the linked questions with no success. Also, I have tried this:

```
RUN mkdir -p ~/miniconda3 && \
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/miniconda3/miniconda.sh  && \
bash ~/miniconda3/miniconda.sh -b -u -p ~/miniconda3  && \
rm -rf ~/miniconda3/miniconda.sh  && \
~/miniconda3/bin/conda init bash  && \
~/miniconda3/bin/conda init zsh
```

Which does work if I execute the commands manually within the container in a bash console, but fails if I paste them into the Dockerfile

Comment: Did you see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68549249/creating-docker-and-anaconda/68571736#68571736)?